# Jquery script stopped working in version 1.11.0

Tags: jquery

what's wrong with this code. It works in previous versions of Jquery but stopped to work in version 1.11.0. This script checks username availability and prints result in div #status.

The script works only partly. It sends request to check-username.php and shows loading.gif and text "please wait" but never prints the result from check-username.php file. It stucks at "Please wait" forever.

Javascript console doesn't show any error messages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pic1 = new Image(16, 11);
pic1.src = "/loading.gif";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nn").change(function () {
        var usr = $("#nn").val();
        var paro = $("#par").val();

        $("#status").html('<img src="/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">Please wait');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/check-username.php",
            data: "nn=" + usr + "&prr=" + paro,
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#status").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                    $("#nn").removeClass('object_ok');
                    $("#nn").addClass("object_error");
                    $(this).html(msg);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: is there absmiddle for align?

Comment: '<img src="/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">Please wait' is invalid html. image tag should be closed `<img />`

Comment: Any chance you can open your console and check for any error?

Comment: I checked the console. There are no errors.

Comment: Why are you registering an `ajaxComplete` event handler in the `success` callback of the AJAX call? Ditch that and just move those three lines of code to be called immediately.

Comment: I removed the line "$("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){}" but the same problem. at "Please wait" forever.

Comment: @C-link: It would only be invalid in XHTML. (And it is not even used in a direct (X)HTML context here, but in a JavaScript/jQuery context.) Please consider not mentioning such stuff in the future, when it is most likely to be irrelevant for the problem at hand … such comments are rather just “noise” under such circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be that ajaxComplete is triggered by the time your success callback function is registered.

This is what you want, right? (sorry I have not actually run it)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
pic1 = new Image(16, 11);
pic1.src = "/loading.gif";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nn").change(function () {
        var usr = $("#nn").val();
        var paro = $("#par").val();

        $("#status").html('<img src="/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">Please wait');
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/check-username.php",
            data: "nn=" + usr + "&prr=" + paro,
            error: function (err) {
                $("#nn").removeClass('object_ok');
                $("#nn").addClass("object_error");
                $("#status").html('an error occurred');
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                $("#nn").addClass('object_ok');
                $("#nn").removeClass("object_error");
                $("#status").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

As a side note, according to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp the img tag:

> In HTML the  tag has no end tag.
>
> In XHTML the  tag must be properly closed.